# Continuity and measurability of differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{C}^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the space of $k$-times differentiable $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the topology of uniform convergence of derivatives of order $1,\dots,k$ on every compact. Moreover let $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C}^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n))$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets in $\mathcal{C}^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$ equipped with the same topology.

Consider the linear differential operator
\begin{align}
R : &\  \mathcal{C}^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n),\\
&f(t)\mapsto r_k\frac{\mathrm{d}^kf}{\mathrm{d}t^k}+r_{k-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-1}f}{\mathrm{d}t^{k-1}}+\cdots+r_0f, \quad r_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, i=0,\dots,k
\end{align}

1. Is $R$ a continuous operator?
2. Is $R$ a measurable operator from $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C}^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)))$ to $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)))$?

(If not, what about the case in which $R$ is defined on the space of smooth functions, i.e. $R\colon \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$?)

Comment: What do you mean with $r_k \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t^k}$, both are elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so we can't just multiply those.

Comment: @NigelOvermars: Sorry, there was a typo: $r_i$'s are constant $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: That makes more sense! Furthermore, since differentiation is a continuous operation from $C^k$ to $C^{k-1}$, doesn't continuity immediately follow from the fact that a composition, sum and multiplication by 'scalars' of continuous functions is also continuous? Also, if it is continuous, then it is also measurable if we have the Borel sigma-algebra.

Comment: @NigelOvermars: Thank you for your comment! I think that you are right (and that was also my initial guess) but since I'm not very familiar with functional analysis I would like to see a more detailed proof (or disproof) of this fact (or perhaps a reference in which this is explained).